# Updates to Membership Users

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to code a user admin page, but the `Membership` API doesn't allow much in terms of direct updates to e.g. password question.  Is there control that I can use for this perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question about updating the password question:

For your .aspx page or .ascx control you can use the following markup:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    A security question is used to assist you in logging in. 
    Because of this, we ask that you provide your password for confirmation 
    of wanting to change the security question associated with your account.
</p>
<ul class="formFields">
    <li>
        <label>
            Question</label><asp:TextBox ID="uxNewQuestion" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxNewRequired" 
             runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxNewQuestion"
            ErrorMessage="New Question is required." 
            ToolTip="New Question is required."
            ValidationGroup="ChangeQuestion">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            Answer</label><asp:TextBox ID="uxNewAnswer" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxConfirmRequired" 
            runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxNewAnswer"
            ErrorMessage="Must Confirm Question" 
            ToolTip="Must Confirm Question" ValidationGroup="ChangeQuestion">
            *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            Your Password:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="uxPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password">
            </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxPasswordRequired" 
             runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxPassword"
             ErrorMessage="Must Provide Correct Password" 
             ToolTip="Must Provide Correct Password"
             ValidationGroup="ChangeQuestion">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="uxSave" runat="server" Text="Save Security Question"
         OnClick="uxSave_Click"
         ValidationGroup="ChangeQuestion" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
         OnClick="uxCancel_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></p>
<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <asp:Literal ID="uxFailureText" runat="server"
         EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

For the code behind you need at least this much code:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(GuidUserID);
string password = uxPassword.Text;
string newquestion = uxNewQuestion.Text;
string newanswer = uxNewAnswer.Text;

if (user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(password, newquestion, newanswer))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Default.aspx", true);
}
else
{
    uxFailureText.Text = string.Format("<p class='error'>There has been a 
         problem updating your security question.</p>");
}
```

If you notice the intro text of the control says that we need the password to confirm the change. This is correct since the membership provider method needs to have the current password passed in along with the old and new security question. Most passwords are one way encrypted so I have provided this control to the user as a self-service type of control instead of being on the administrative side of things.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Comment: changepassword control does not let you change the password question

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  Yes, I saw the provider needs the password to change the question etc. but I was just wondering if a mechanism already exists.  Looks like not, so your code will be a good kick-start.  BTW, +1 for your effort, and I wish I could do another +1 for how you mark up forms :-)